# Display freight volume by city on a geographic map

Tags: software-recommendations, origin-destination, flow-map

I have been requested to show on a geographic map the volume (in meters cubed m3) of freight (parts) that ship to various cities (Canada/USA).
The idea is to show which cities receive the most freight by volume.

Presently the only mapping tool I have accessible is Microsoft Mappoint 2002.

Is there another webbased tool that I could use that does a good job of showing volumes relative to each other?
Mappoint has a feature to show sized pie charts  - is the best type of method of showing total volume by city along with the individual contributors?

Update1:

I am not trying to show the flow of parts - only the size of origin and destination.  For example does Toronto, Ontario have 100m3 of parts and Buffalo, New York only 30m3 of parts?

Comment: @whuber - I didn't even realize there was a GIS site!

Answer (score 1):

You need [flow mapping software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_map). There's a list of free* tools at the end of that Wikipedia entry. I heard good things about JFlowMap, but I have not used it myself.

*Depending on commercial use, in some cases.

Comment: I thought that "along with the individual contributors" means that he has the origins.

Comment: Depends if you interpret "individual contributors" as places or as "freight(parts)". Regardless, the OP needs to further clarify.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Totally agree on the clarification.

Comment: John, you can use QGIS plugin FlowMapper to depict inter nodal mass flows. Check the plugin from the repo: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/